# How do I change the labels of the style variables in the legend of a seaborn plot?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am trying to change a specific part of the legend in my plot in seaborn.

I wrote the following code to display a plot in seaborn. The plot can be seen below.

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data = weekly_port_ret,
             x='week',y='R',hue='high_leverage',style='gsector')

ax.set(title='Weekly Portfolio Returns - Daily Rebalancing',
       xlabel='Week in 2020',
       ylabel='Weekly Return'
       )

plt.show()
```

I am just trying to change where it says "20.0" in the legend to "Industrial", and where it says "45.0" to "IT". Does anyone know how to do this?

[My plot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP1cH.png)

Comment: Map the values in the gsector column of the dataframe to the correct category name. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678874/7758804. Managing and cleaning data should occur prior to plotting.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `gsector` column to the values (Industrial and IT) and map it so that you can see the legend as you want... Updated code below.

I used some dummy data, but your code should work as well.

Refer [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for more info..

```
mysector = {20:'Industrial', 45:'IT'} 
ax = sns.lineplot(data = weekly_port_ret.assign(gsector=weekly_port_ret['gsector'].map(mysector)),
             x='week',y='R',hue='high_leverage',style='gsector')

ax.set(title='Weekly Portfolio Returns - Daily Rebalancing',
       xlabel='Week in 2020',
       ylabel='Weekly Return'
       )

plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]