# How to replace values based on dictionary and index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataset with two columns: order and text.  For some orders, the text needs to be replaced.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Order': ['OrderF14-47', 'OrderF13-43'],
    'Text': ['disclose the information', 'confirm withhold s. 88']})
    
print(df)
```

I have a means of replacing the information based on the order column:

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(df.loc[df['Order'] == 'OrderF14-47', 'Text'].iloc[0], 'disclose under s. 22.'))
print(df['Text'])
```

The problem is that I have ~216 rows that need replacing. The code is taking a very long time to run.

I've looked into [dictionary replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict-preserve-nans), but they seem to identify the item to replace based on the value.  I want the item to be identified based on the value of a different column.

So I looked at dictionary replacements based on index and found this:

```
df = df.set_index('Order')

di = {'OrderF14-47': "disclose the information s. 22"}

df = df['Text'].put(di.keys(), di.values())


print(df)
```

But this results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'put'
```

Comment: For reference, `Series.put` was [removed in Pandas 1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You can just use [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) to set the value:

```
df.loc[df['Order'] == 'OrderF14-47', 'Text'] = 'disclose under s. 22.'
```

`df` is then:

```
         Order                    Text
0  OrderF14-47   disclose under s. 22.
1  OrderF13-43  confirm withhold s. 88
```

Comment: thanks wjandrea!  Your solution takes 0.004774332046508789 seconds; my original solution takes 0.005198001861572266 seconds.  Not sure if that extra millisecond will solve the problem given there are only 216 lines - will test when I get back to my computer in a few hours.

Comment: @oymonk If you're not testing it at scale, that timing is probably meaningless. There's substantial overhead so the difference could be just noise.