# replace() method works partially on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I try to replace values in DataFrame in this way:

```
dstestsmoke = dstest.copy()
dstestsmoke['smoker'] = dstestsmoke['smoker'].replace('Yes', 1)
dstestsmoke['smoker'] = dstestsmoke['smoker'].replace('No', 0)
dstestsmoke
```

and the result was as follows:

```
    total_bill  tip sex smoker  day time    size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  0   Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    0   Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    0   Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    Male    0   Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    Female  0   Sun Dinner  4
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
239 29.03   5.92    Male    0   Sat Dinner  3
240 27.18   2.00    Female  1   Sat Dinner  2
241 22.67   2.00    Male    1   Sat Dinner  2
242 17.82   1.75    Male    0   Sat Dinner  2
243 18.78   3.00    Female  0   Thur    Dinner  2
```

It is ok, no any questions.

---

But, later I try to do it again, in same manner:

```
dstreat = dstest.copy()
dstreat['sex'] = dstest['sex'].replace('Male', 0)
dstreat['sex'] = dstest['sex'].replace('Female', 1)
dstreat
```

and the result was as follows:

```
total_bill  tip sex smoker  day time    size
0   16.99   1.01    1   No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    Male    No  Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    1   No  Sun Dinner  4
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
239 29.03   5.92    Male    No  Sat Dinner  3
240 27.18   2.00    1   Yes Sat Dinner  2
241 22.67   2.00    Male    Yes Sat Dinner  2
242 17.82   1.75    Male    No  Sat Dinner  2
243 18.78   3.00    1   No  Thur    Dinner  2
```

If I change the order of the lines of code, it turns out the opposite:

```
dstreat = dstest.copy()
dstreat['sex'] = dstest['sex'].replace('Female', 0)
dstreat['sex'] = dstest['sex'].replace('Male', 1)
dstreat
```

result:

```
total_bill  tip sex smoker  day time    size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    1   No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    1   No  Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    1   No  Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    Female  No  Sun Dinner  4
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
239 29.03   5.92    1   No  Sat Dinner  3
240 27.18   2.00    Female  Yes Sat Dinner  2
241 22.67   2.00    1   Yes Sat Dinner  2
242 17.82   1.75    1   No  Sat Dinner  2
243 18.78   3.00    Female  No  Thur    Dinner  2
```

---

How can I fix such case? BTW, there are other text values in this DataFrame (for example, for the `day` column) and if I apply the same code as above to other columns, I will get the same result - only one value will change

Comment: Remember that a column can only contain a single datatype.  Don't you actually want `dstreat['sex'] = dstest['sex'] == 'Male'`?

Comment: You most likely should `map` the values with `{'Male': 0, 'Female': 1}`, it's unnecessary to use two steps.

Comment: Great thanks for your help! `map` indeed works fine at my case. 

Also solution shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250771/remap-values-in-pandas-column-with-a-dict-preserve-nans