# New column, sampled from list, based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
values = [1,2,3,2,3,1]
colors = ['r','g','b']
expected_output = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'g', 'b', 'r'] # how to create this in pandas?

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values})
df['colors'] = expected_output
```

I want to make a new column in my dataframe where the colors are selected based on values in an existing column. I remember doing this in xarray with a vectorised indexing trick, but I can't remember if the same thing is possible in pandas. It feels like it should be a basic indexing task.

The current answers are a nice start, thanks! They take a bit too much advantage of the numerical nature of "values" though. I'd rather something generic that would also work if say

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

I guess the "map" method probably still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code**

use numpy indexing

```
import numpy as np
df['colors'] = np.array(colors)[df['values'] - 1]
```

df

```
   values color
0       1     r
1       2     g
2       3     b
3       2     g
4       3     b
5       1     r
```

If you want to solve this problem using only Pandas, use `map` function. (with @Onyambu comment)

```
m = dict(enumerate(colors, 1))
df['colors'] = df['values'].map(m)
```

Comment: no need of `dict comprehension`. just use `m = dict(enumerate(colors, 1))`

Comment: @Onyambu 
you are right! I habitually used the code because I always mapped it to key: number.

Comment: Nice! The map method feels the most natural to me. The mapping dictionary is also nice to construct for any type of values, e.g. `m = dict(zip(unique_values, colors))`

Comment: @BenFarmer mapping a dict is an optimized operation ([#2 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933438/19123103) is a bit relevant even though the context is different). It’s possibly the fastest way to do your task especially if there are a lot of colors to map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas.cut):

```
df["colors"] = pd.cut([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], 3, labels=["r", "g", "b"])
```

Result:

```
   values colors
0       1      r
1       2      g
2       3      b
3       2      g
4       3      b
5       1      r
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version, using [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas-categorical):

```py
colors = ["r", "g", "b"]
df["colors"] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df["values"] - 1, categories=colors)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   values   colors
0       1        r
1       2        g
2       3        b
3       2        g
4       3        b
5       1        r
```