# Sort a Dataframe and count a value with percentages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Kind   Status
1      True
2      False
3      True
2      False
2      True
```

I counted the kinds with it `df.Kind.sort_values()`
and got this:

```
1       1
2       3
3       1
```

Now I want to see how much of Kind 2 are true or false as number and percent. Like this:

```
Art  True  False
  2     1      2
  2  0.33   0.66
```

Can someone help me? 
Best regards

Comment: Check out the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383094/python-pandas-numpy-true-false-to-1-0-mapping)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### crosstab + div

Using [`pandas.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['Kind'], df['Status'])

res[['Pct False', 'Pct True']] = res.div(res.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

print(res)

Status  False  True  Pct False   Pct True
Kind                                     
1           0     1   0.000000   1.000000
2           2     1   0.666667   0.333333
3           0     1   0.000000   1.000000
```

In my opinion, this is the most natural way to display your data. Combining counts with percentages in a single series is not recommended.

#### crosstab + crosstab normalize

Alternatively, you can join a couple of `crosstab` results, one normalized, the other not.

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['Kind'], df['Status'])\
        .join(pd.crosstab(df['Kind'], df['Status'], normalize='index'), rsuffix='_pct')

print(res)

Status  False  True  False_pct  True_pct
Kind                                    
1           0     1   0.000000  1.000000
2           2     1   0.666667  0.333333
3           0     1   0.000000  1.000000
```

#### crosstab normalize only

If you are looking only for percentages, you can just use the `normalize` argument:

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['Kind'], df['Status'], normalize='index')

print(res)

Status     False     True 
Kind                      
1       0.000000  1.000000
2       0.666667  0.333333
3       0.000000  1.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for pivot by `count`s:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Kind','Status']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
#alternative solution, slowier in large data
#df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Kind'], df['Status'])
print (df1)
Status  False  True 
Kind                
1           0      1
2           2      1
3           0      1
```

Then divide by `sum` and append to original:

```
df = df1.append(df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0)).sort_index()
print (df)
Status     False     True 
Kind                      
1       0.000000  1.000000
1       0.000000  1.000000
2       2.000000  1.000000
2       0.666667  0.333333
3       0.000000  1.000000
3       0.000000  1.000000
```

---

```
print (df.loc[2])
Status     False     True 
Kind                      
2       2.000000  1.000000
2       0.666667  0.333333
```

But if want avoid converting `integer`s to `float`s change `append` to `join` and for unique columns add [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df1.join(df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1), axis=0).add_prefix('pct '))
print (df)
Status  False  True  pct False  pct True
Kind                                    
1           0     1   0.000000  1.000000
2           2     1   0.666667  0.333333
3           0     1   0.000000  1.000000

print (df.loc[[2]])

Status  False  True  pct False  pct True
Kind                                    
2           2     1   0.666667  0.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
g = df.loc[df['Kind']==2].groupby(['Kind', 'Status']).size().unstack()
pd.concat([g,g.apply(lambda x: round(x / (x[False]+x[True]), 2), axis=1)])
```

Output:

```
Status  False   True
Kind        
2   2.00    1.00
2   0.67    0.33
```