# Convert Categorical data to numeric percentage in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this, all categorical values:

```
col1    col2
0   A   x
1   A   y
2   A   x
3   A   z
4   A   z
5   A   z
6   B   x
7   B   y
8   B   x
```

I want to group this by "col1" and get the percentage of time I get values of "col2" in separate columns. Like:

```
    col1    x    y       z
0   A     33.33  16.67   50.0
1   B     66.67  33.37   0.0
```

I tried pivot table that gives me only count of each values of a column but how to get it in percentage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Dataframe and count a value with percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681409/sort-a-dataframe-and-count-a-value-with-percentages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make a cross-tabulation of two factors (`col1` and `col2`) with the frequency normalized over each row. To do this you can use [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize` set to `index`:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('aaaaaabbb'), 'col2': list('xyxzzzxyx')})
>> pd.crosstab(df['col1'], df['col2'], normalize='index') * 100
col2    x           y           z
col1            
a       33.333333   16.666667   50.0
b       66.666667   33.333333   0.0
```

If you want to use multiple factors, just call `crosstab` with a list of factors:

```
>> df['col3'] = list('112231345')
>> pd.crosstab([df['col1'], df['col3']], df['col2'], normalize='index') * 100
        col2    x           y           z
col1    col3            
a       1       33.333333   33.333333   33.333333
        2       50.000000   0.000000    50.000000
        3       0.000000    0.000000    100.000000
b       3       100.000000  0.000000    0.000000
        4       0.000000    100.000000  0.000000
        5       100.000000  0.000000    0.000000
```

If you want to round up, just call `round`:

```
>> round(pd.crosstab(df['col1'], df['col2'], normalize='index') * 100, 2)
col2    x       y       z
col1            
a       33.33   16.67   50.0
b       66.67   33.33   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I was trying pivot table and trying to create a lambda function.

Comment: np! don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: how to do this with 2 columns as index?