# Python | count number of False statements in 3 rows

Tags: python, pandas, countif

Columns L,M,N of my dataframe are populated with 'true' and 'false' statements(1000 rows). I would like to create a new column 'count_false' that will return the number of times 'false' statement occurred in columns L,M and N.

Any tips appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype of those columns? Please show your example dataframe and what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can negate your dataframe and sum over `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 3)), columns=list('LMN')).astype(bool)

df['Falses'] = (~df).sum(1)

print(df)

       L      M      N  Falses
0   True  False   True       1
1   True  False  False       2
2   True   True   True       0
3  False   True  False       2
4  False  False   True       2
```

If you have additional columns, you can filter accordingly:

```
df['Falses'] = (~df[list('LMN')]).sum(1)
```

Comment: This is the simplest. To count trues with a list of relevant column names: df["Trues"] = df[["col1, "col2", "coln"]].sum(1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  `df[df==false].count()`

Comment: Well that won't work because the Boolean `False` is capitalised. Is the OP working with strings or bools?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383094/python-pandas-numpy-true-false-to-1-0-mapping) True and False equal to 1 and 0 in Python, therefore something like the line three of the following example should solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[True, False, True],[False, False, False],[True, False, True],[False, False, True]], columns=['L','M','N'])
df['count_false'] = 3 - (df['L']*1 + df['M']*1 + df['N']*1)
```

Comment: This one instead fixes the solution proposed by @TeamDataViz.:
df[df==False].count(axis=1)