# Pandas.get_dummies return to two columns(_Y and _N) instead of one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `sklearn` to train a decision tree based on my dataset.

When I was trying to slicing the data to (outcome:Y, and predicting variables:X), it turns out that the outcome (my label) is in `True`/`False`:

```
#data slicing 
X = df.values[:,3:27] #X are the sets of predicting variable, dropping unique_id and student name here
Y = df.values[:,'OffTask'] #Y is our predicted value (outcome), it is in the 3rd column
```

This is how I do, but I do not know whether this is the right approach:

```
#convert the label "OffTask" to dummy 

df1 = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=["OffTask"])
df1
```

My trouble is the dataset df1 return my label `Offtask` to `OffTask_N` and `OffTask_Y`

Can someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Is this about pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I map True/False to 1/0 in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383094/how-can-i-map-true-false-to-1-0-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I don't think it is the same question. I am not sure how to convert the list and reuse the list.

Comment: sklearn can take True/False as a y vector and do the fitting just fine, there really is no need for you to convert.
But if you really insist on seeing 0 and 1 you can use `df['OffTask'] = df['OffTask'].astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

get_dummies is used for converting nominal string values to integer. It returns as many as column as many unique string values are available in columns eg:

```
df={'color':['red','green','blue'],'price':[1200,3000,2500]}
my_df=pd.DataFrame(df)
pd.get_dummies(my_df)
```

In your case you can drop first value, wherever value is null can be considered it will be first value

Comment: Hi, thanks. This is what I did. I just drop the _N in this case, but I am just wondering whether there is a better way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could make the **`pd.get_dummies`** to return only one column by setting **`drop_first=True`**

```
y = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=["OffTask"], drop_first=True)
```

But this is not the recommended way to convert the label to binaries. I would suggest using labelbinarizer for this purpose.

Example:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame({'OffTask':['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']}))

#
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1]])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I am still a little confused how the prepocessing has convert the list to binary in this case? How could it be return to my dataset?

Comment: It will create a dummy variable for each unique value in a `list ` / `pd.Series`. Then dummy variables will be 1, if the corresponding element is belongs to that value.

Comment: Go through through link for detailed explanation. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#preprocessing-targets