# Create a Boolean column based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe of 11 columns and I want to create a new 0,1 column based on values in two of those columns.

I have already tried using np.where to create other columns but it doesnt work for this one.

```
train["location"] = np.where(3750901.5068 <= train["x"] <= 3770901.5068 
and -19268905.6133 <= train['y'] <= -19208905.6133, 1, 0)
```

I get this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 8):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.isin which will be a better solution. Also yes you need parenthesis and & instead of "and" . Documentation for pandas.DataFrame.isin https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[100,110,120,111,109],'b':[120,345,124,119,127]})
df['c']=np.where((df['a'].isin([100,111])) & (df['b'].isin([120,128])),1,0)
```

In your case it would be:

```
train["location"]=np.where(((train["x"].isin([3750901.5068,3770901.5069])) & (train["y"].isin([-19268905.6133,-19268905.6132])),1,0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you even need `np.where` here.  To element-wise `and` two series, use `&` here instead of `and`.  See: [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

Also, `3750901.5068 <= train["x"] <= 3770901.5068` seems to be internally translated by python into `(3750901.5068 <= train["x"]) and (train["x"] <= 3770901.5068)`, which again, has `and` and won't work.  So you'll need to either explicitly split each one up into e.g. `(3750901.5068 <= train["x"]) & (train["x"] <= 3770901.5068)` or use `Series.between` e.g. `train["x"].between(3750901.5068, 3770901.5068, inclusive=True)`.  See: [How to select rows in a DataFrame between two values, in Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617845/how-to-select-rows-in-a-dataframe-between-two-values-in-python-pandas)

You'll also need parentheses for the two arguments to `&`.

So the end result should look like

`train["location"] = train["x"].between(3750901.5068, 3770901.5068, inclusive=True) & train['y'].between(-19268905.6133, -19208905.6133, inclusive=True)`

This will give you a series of bools (Trues and Falses).  These are already just 0s and 1s under-the-hood.  If you really want 0s and 1s, you can pick a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383094/how-can-i-map-true-false-to-1-0-in-a-pandas-dataframe).  For example, `train.location = train.location.astype(int)`

Comment: Since you've linked to that question, I also recommend going through [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/4909087) to that question.

Comment: wow, that's a thorough answer. Reading it made me realize that my answer here is incorrect, since `foo < train['y'] < bar` will be translated into `foo < train['y'] and train['y'] < bar`.

Comment: You can use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) instead.