# Pandas map returning all values as NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mapping

when mapping target variable, 'diabetes' (False patient has no diabetes, True patient has diabetes) to 0 (False) and 1 (True). All of entries come back as NaNs

I thought may be 'diabetes' isn't a true str and I need to convert to string first. Tried the following code:

```
diab_data['diabetes'] = diab_data['diabetes'].astype(str)

diab_data["diabetes"] = diab_data["diabetes"].map({'False':0, 'True':1})
```

I need values below to be either 0 (False) or 1 (True). All values return as NaN

Original Output:

```
patient diabetes
0         False
1         True
2         True 
3         True
4         False
```

Output after mapping:

```
patient diabetes
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27362540

Comment: It is weird, but your solution should working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need map for this:

```
diab_data["diabetes"].astype(int)
```

Also you are using the bool values as string , use `True` instead of `'True'` for example under `map()`:

```
df["diabetes"].map({False:0, True:1})
```

Comment: That worked thank you. Yea I did not need to put '' or "" around values for the variables as they are boolean values. That was the culprit