# Unable to replace True and False in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data looks like the below

```
Code  Col1  Col2   col3   col4  col5 col6    Col7  Col8
0    A      nan     nan   False  c    12     True   8
1    B      1       Nan   True   ab    1     True   9
2    C      Nan     5     True   rr    89.7  False  78.8
3    D      34.4    0     True   tr    123   True   90.3
```

I have more than 1 column having true/false data, the column will not always be in the same location and their number could defer, i want to replace the True anf False text with 1 or 0 numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(r'path.xls', sheet_name='mydata')
#print(df)

def foo_bar(x):
    if x == 'True':
        return x.replace('True', '1')

    if x == 'False':
        return x.replace('False', '0')

df.applymap(foo_bar)

for v in df['col 7']:
    print(v)
```

The print is showing :

```
True
True
False
True
1.0
```

the values are not being changed to True and False as expected

Comment: I think need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65395517/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael   That will not work in that question all the data is True or False, mine can have empty cell, text or numbers.

Comment: hmmm, do you try `replace` like mentioned in comment above?

Comment: @jezrael   I have and it gave me the following bug: 1 1 0 1 1.0 so even though i have 4 rows i'm still getting an additional 1.0 when i print for v in df['col 7']:
    print(v) it should be 1 1 0 1

Comment: For me working very well. There is not `True, False` and `1.0` value together?

Comment: Fixed my file had a trailing data in that column for some reason so worked well when i copied only the table in question, thank you for your assistance :)