# Creating a new column based on if-else condition using several other columns

Tags: python, pandas

```py
if data['weight'] < 50 | data['blood_diseases'] == 1 | data['age'] > 65 | data['hemoglobin_level'] < 12 | data['period_between_successive_blood_donations'] < 3:
    data['can'] = 0
else:
    data['can'] = 1
```

I have an error

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please add brackets to your if-else statement. It will solve your problem.
like this:

```
if  (data['weight'] < 50)|(data['blood_diseases'] == 1)|(data['age'] > 65)|  (data['hemoglobin_level'] < 12) | (data['period_between_successive_blood_donations'] < 3):
    data['can'] = 0
else:
    data['can'] = 1
```

or

```
if  (data['weight'] < 50) or (data['blood_diseases'] == 1) or (data['age'] > 65) or  (data['hemoglobin_level'] < 12) or (data['period_between_successive_blood_donations'] < 3):
    data['can'] = 0
else:
    data['can'] = 1
```

Comment: With `or` the parentheses can be left out.

Comment: It doeasnt work either, I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `if`/`else`. The expression `if a` where `a` is a Series does not make sense, because there are several possible ways to interpret a Series as a single boolean value. This is one reason for getting the error you see.
2. You also need to enforce the desired evaluation order by using parentheses:

   - not only will `data['weight'] < 50 | data['blood_diseases']` evaluate as `data['weight'] < (50 | data['blood_diseases'])`, because `|` has a higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `<`,
   - but also `data['weight'] < 50 | data['blood_diseases'] == 1` will evaluate as `(data['weight'] < (50 | data['blood_diseases'])) and ((50 | data['blood_diseases']) == 1)` due to [chaining of comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

     This again will try to interpret two Series as single boolean values in an expression `a and b` which is the second reason for getting the error.
3. Don't use `data['can'] = 0` or `data['can'] = 1`. It will assign a constant value to the column, instead of evaluating the other columns row-wise.

Just assign the expression to the new column.

```
data['can'] = (data['weight'] < 50) | (data['blood_diseases'] == 1) | (data['age'] > 65) | (data['hemoglobin_level'] < 12) | (data['period_between_successive_blood_donations'] < 3)
```

If you really need `0`/`1` instead of boolean values, you can convert them:

[How can I map True/False to 1/0 in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383094/how-can-i-map-true-false-to-1-0-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where`

```
import numpy as np

mask = (data['weight'] < 50) | (data['blood_diseases'] == 1) | \
(data['age'] > 65) | (data['hemoglobin_level'] < 12) | \
(data['period_between_successive_blood_donations'] < 3)
data["can"] = np.where(mask,1,0)
```